# How to use this portaudio Go binding?

Tags: go, cgo, portaudio

I'm trying to dynamically play audio in a Go application. Basically the only way I found was to use a Go binding to call a C library, more specifically portaudio.

I found [this binding](https://github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio) but I don't know how to use it. I downloaded these [pre-compiled DLLs](https://github.com/spatialaudio/portaudio-binaries) and replaced the lines

```
/*
#cgo pkg-config: portaudio-2.0
#include <portaudio.h>
extern PaStreamCallback* paStreamCallback;
*/
```

with

```
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -LC:\portaudio-binaries -lportaudio
#include "portaudio.h"
extern PaStreamCallback* paStreamCallback;
*/
```

but when I try to compile the Go project I still get

```
cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

I also got this error when trying to import versions of portaudio I compiled using mingw. Its output had the format of a .la file alongside a .libs folder, which contained a .dll file plus others. But I'm not sure how I'm supposed to import this format of libraries.